# Sum across joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, unique

Consider the following scenario: a user has one or more (bank) accounts. The the historical changes in the accounts' balances are tracked in a table. I would like to display a history of the user's funds in time, across all of his accounts. These are the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `balances` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And here is some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
  (1,'Bob');

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `user_id`)
VALUES
  (1,1),
  (2,1);

INSERT INTO `balances` (`id`, `account_id`, `amount`, `created_at`)
VALUES
  (1,1,100, '2012-01-01'),
  (2,1,150, '2012-01-02'),
  (3,2,1000,'2012-01-04'),
  (4,2,1100,'2012-01-08'),
  (5,1,175, '2012-01-10');
```

A user is only allowed one deposit/withdrawal per day across accounts, so the `created_at` values can be considered unique.

Given the sample data, the result of the query I would like to write should be this:

```
|'2012-01-01'|100 |
|'2012-01-02'|150 |
|'2012-01-04'|1150|
|'2012-01-08'|1250|
|'2012-01-10'|1275|
```

The plan is the following:

1. Grab all unique dates from the balances table.
2. For each date select the latest balance in each account so that the balance's date does not exceed the date in step 1.
3. Sum the amounts found in step 2 ignoring NULL values. A NULL value would mean that the first recorded balance for that account was for a later date.

I am having trouble formulating the condition for step 2.

[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8273d/1)

Comment: can you give sample desired output?

Comment: @Omesh: Look at the last code listing.

Comment: I have been messing with the SQL fiddle and I have to say I'm not even sure it is possible in SQL (though I'm far from being an expert). I think you would need to have an account value for each day if you wanted to do this in SQL unless there's a special trick I don't know about.

Comment: It seems to me that you need a subquery which would isolate and sum last entries per account before or equal to current row's date. [Here is an article which you might find helpful](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Comment: In the sample data for accounts, the account_id's seem wrong) ("11221"), the intended output suggests "12121".

Comment: @wildplasser The account_ids play no part in the output. The output reads "for any date on which a change of balance of any account was made, this is the sum of the balance of all accounts".

Comment: I see. I misread, and thought you wanted the cumulative sum per account. Sorry!

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur Note that your SQL Fiddle is for SQL Server 2008 R2, but the OP is after MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id,created_at,sum(accAmount) from
(
select a.id account_id,a.user_id user_id, dt.created_at created_at,
( select amount from balances b3 where (b3.account_id=a.id)
and b3.created_at=
(select max(created_at) as lastAccDate from balances b
where b.created_at<=dt.created_at and b.account_id=a.id)
) AccAmount
from accounts a,
(select distinct created_at from balances) dt
) AccountAmounts
group by user_id,created_at
order by 2
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Is there a way to generalize the query to show the sum of all accounts at a certain date?

Comment: @NickolayKolev If you need sum for all users accounts just change `select created_at, sum(accAmount) from ..... )AccountAmounts where created_at<=@YourDate group by created_at order by created_at DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (understanding with my pure English :);

```
SELECT b.created_at, Sum(amount) amount, u.id, u.name 
FROM balances b 
LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.id=b.account_id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=a.user_id 
GROUP BY b.created_at 
ORDER BY b.created_at
```

And got this result;

```
created_at  amount    id    name
2012-01-01  100       1     Bob
2012-01-02  150       1     Bob
2012-01-04  1000      1     Bob
2012-01-08  1100      1     Bob
2012-01-10  175       1     Bob
```

I think all date fields are uniq as you wrote.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the desired output. See the last code listing for the result I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big MySQL user, but I have created a query which works on MS SQL Server.  It's not particularly performant (3 subqueries and a Distinct, boo!), so you might want to think about whether there are better ways than simply deriving this in a single query.

```
SELECT
  b.created_at,
  SUM(b.amount),

  (
    SELECT SUM(acc_amt)
    FROM
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT b2.account_id,
        (
           SELECT TOP 1 b3.amount
           FROM balances AS b3
           WHERE b3.account_id = b2.account_id
           AND b3.created_at <= b.created_at
           ORDER BY b3.created_at DESC
        ) AS acc_amt
        FROM balances AS b2
        WHERE b2.created_at <= b.created_at
      ) temp_bal
  )

FROM
  balances AS b
GROUP BY
  b.created_at
```

To convert to MySQL you'll need to remove the **TOP 1** and add a **LIMIT 1** after 'DESC' in the b3 sub query, and tinker until MySQL is happy with the syntax.  I will have a go and see if I can convert it.

Comment: MySQL is not happy with accessing `b.created_at` in the inner query. According to its documentation this is the intended behaviour.